# Conditions for an ideal gas to act as a heat reservoir

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm trying to understand what are the required conditions for an ideal gas in one spatial dimension to  act as a heat reservoir. **I would appreciate answers that don't use the terms *heat*, *temperature*, *heat capacity*, *entropy* unless they are well defined *for the system described in the question*. (I'm trying to find reasoning from first principles)**

I'll start with a helpful calculation: An ideal gas with $N$ particles in one dimension has energy which is proportional to $\sum_{i=1}^Np_i^2$, where $p_i$ is the momentum of the $i$'th particle. Therefore, the number of microstates of the ideal gas with a total energy $E$ is proportional to $E^{N-1}$. Let's denote the constant of proportionality $\alpha^{N-1}$, therefore the number of microstates with energy $E$ is $\Omega(E)=(\alpha E)^{N-1}$. These three equations follow: $$\log \Omega(E)=(N-1)\log(\alpha E)$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial E}\log \Omega(E)=\frac{N-1}{E}$$ $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial E^2}\log \Omega(E)=-\frac{N-1}{E^2}$$

Now, let's suppose that some thermodynamic system $S$ is coupled to this one-dimensional ideal gas, which I denote by $S'$, and that the combined system is isolated with total energy $E_\text{tot}$. The coupling lets energy flow between the systems, but the interface between them does not allow the "flow" of volume, particles etc..

Using the principle of equal a priori probabilities, we assume that all microstates of the combined system have the same probability. It follows that the probability $p(s)$ of a microstate $s$ of $S$, with energy $E_s$, is proportional to $\Omega({E_\text{tot}-E_s)}$. Taylor expanding around $E_s=0$ we get: $$p(s)\propto e^{\log\Omega({E_\text{tot}-E_s)}}=e^{\log\Omega({E_\text{tot})}-\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}(N-1)+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}\right)^2\right)}$$
where the leading coefficient of the $\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}\right)^2\right)$ term is $N-1$.

Denoting $\beta=\frac{N-1}{E_\text{tot}}$, we get: $$p(s)\propto e^{-\beta E_s+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}\right)^2\right)}$$

(The proportionality means that the factor of proportion does not depend on $s$).

You are probably aware that I'm following the derivation of the canonical ensemble. At this point of the derivation, usually the $\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}\right)^2\right)$ is omited, owing to the fact that $S'$ is a heat reservoir. This is the point I'd like to better understand, and here are my questions:

1. When is it justified to omit the term? I understand that it is required that $\left(\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}\right)^2$ is small compared to its coefficient $N-1$. But when can I expect this condition to hold (especially noting that usually $N-1$ is taken very large)? I mean, suppose that the only variable that I directly control in the experiment is $E_\text{tot}$. How can I know which values of $E_\text{tot}$ I should provide in order for the energy of the system to be distributed between $S$ and $S'$ such that $\left(\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}\right)^2$ is indeed small enough?
2. When can the ideal gas behave as a heat reservoir for small $N$, such as $N=1,2$?
3. Does the mass of the particles in the ideal gas matter?
4. What are we assuming about the interaction between the systems $S$ and $S'$?
5. Suppose that the system $S$ is also an ideal gas (in three dimensions), and that its interaction with $S'$ is such that $S'$ can actually only influence only one specific particle in $S$. In other words, the energy flow from $S'$ to $S$ allows for the energy to go only to one specific particle in $S$. Could $S'$ still be considered a heat reservoir in this case? If no, what condition is not satisfied?
6. For a general system $S'$ (not necessarily and ideal gas), what are the conditions on $S'$, $S$ and the interactions between them that allow the treatment of $S'$ as a heat reservoir? I'd appreciate if the answer to this  question (question 6) is given in two versions: one without referring to heat, temperature, heat capacity, entropy and the other which does includes these terms (or some of them)

---

**Edit 1:**

An additional question:

7. Does the question whether a system behaves as a heat reservoir depend also on the specific calculation of interest? For example, if we are interested in the extensive property $A$ which is defined as the sum over all particles $i$ of $E_i^{10^{10^{10}}}$, where $E_i$ is the energy of the $i$'th particle. Calculating its expected value involves integrating the integrand $A\cdot p(s)\text{d}s$. Here, clearly the integrand might be dominated by microstates $s$ with high energy, which seems to suggest that we can't use the standard canonical ensemble.

Comment: Your analysis has important, but hidden points related to dynamics of such systems. In order to exchange energy ( heat), systems S and S' has to exchange kinetic energy between particles. It is important to note that if such exchange is not efficient, the whole process may take time, and I would not exclude particular causes when thermodynamic equilibrium is even not possible here. For example for 1 dimensional systems, exchange occur only in one point!

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.

In statistical physics, we are ultimately interested in calculating statistical magnitudes such as the mean energy of the system $S$. This is given by:
$$\langle E\rangle=\int E_s\cdot p(s)\text{d}s$$
where the integral is over all microstates $s$ of $S$. The question of whether $S'$ can be considered as a heat reservoir is equivalent to the question of whether we can use the canonical ensemble relation $p(s)\propto e^{-\beta E_s}$ (without the higher order terms). Now, when integrating over $s$, surely we will encounter states with $E_s$ such that $\frac{E_s}{E_\text{tot}}$is too large for us to be able to omit the higher order terms in $p(s)$. However, it is actually not so straight forward, since the integral can be over many different values of $s$ with the same energy $E_s$, and this multiplicity can be large enough to amplify even the higher orders of $E_s$ in $p(s)$. This multiplicity is $\Omega_S(E_s)$, and the integral can be written as:
$$\langle E\rangle=\int E\cdot \Omega_S(E)p(s_E)\text{d}E$$
where $s_E$ is a representative microstate of $S$ with energy $E$. This integral is helpful since it samples each value of $p(s)$ exactly once. It shows us that the contribution to the integral of a specific energy $E_s$ is 
$E_s \Omega_S(E_s)p(s)$. From here we conclude that we can neglect higher order terms $e^{\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{E_s}{E\text{tot}}\right)^2\right)}$ if $E_s \Omega_S(E_s)e^{\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{E_s}{E\text{tot}}\right)^2\right)}$ is very small compared to other energies. $\Omega_S(E_s)p(s)$ is exactly $P(E)$ and is given by:
$$P(E)\propto \Omega_S(E)\Omega_{S'}(E_\text{tot}-E)$$
It happens that usually $P(E)$ is *much* larger for some energy that the other energies, and thus this energy dominates the integral. Usually this energy is small enough that the higher order terms of $p(s)$ can be neglected.

The conclusion is that in order that we can use the canonical ensemble rule, we need to count the number of states $\Omega_S(E)$ and $\Omega_{S'}(E_\text{tot}-E)$, and make sure that $E\cdot\Omega_S(E)\Omega_{S'}(E_\text{tot}-E)$ is highly dominated by a small enough energy $E$. Obviously, this shows that there is dependence on the number of degrees of freedom in both $S$ and $S'$.

Comment: This analysis looks completely like computation of exponential integral by stepest phase method ( I am not sure if this is correct English terminology. It is typical method used for following from Faynman path integral to classical physics)